# Getting rid of characters between 2 others in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have strings, shortened looks like this

```
var string = "<p> Text <p>"
var STRING = "<strong> Text <strong>"
```

I want to remove *anything* that is between the characters `<` and `>`  so I can call it like `string.removeTags`:

```
console.log(string) // Text
```

Comment: What's your intended output?

Comment: @SaugatAcharya Sorry, I have included this in the question now.

Comment: string.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")

Comment: Do you need a string.removeTags method to strip out the HTML? Are you doing this in the browser?

Comment: I'm not doing this in a browser, I'm using it for a chat bot. Using an API and some of the text includes these tags and I don't want them to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want something like this:

```js
   
var string = "<p> Text <p>";

String.prototype.removeTags = function() {
    return this.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');
}

console.log(string.removeTags());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
   

 var string1 = "<p> Text <p>";
 var string2 = string1.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
 alert(string2);
```

maybe some more info:

The regex matches:

a pattern that starts with <

then has any characters besides > ([^>]*)

then has a closing bracket >

this gets replaced with ''